# Radio Buttons and javascript, wrong output

Tags: javascript, html

below is the code for my radio buttons,

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_north autocomplete='off'>North
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_south" autocomplete='off'>South
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_east" autocomplete='off'>East
</label>
```

and below is my javascript,

```
var form = document.getElementById("info_form");
alert(form.elements["radio_north"].value);
```

but I get 'on' on alert, instead of north, south or east. I tried my best but cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: Add single quote to your HTML code: `id="radio_north' autocomplete='off'`

Comment: Does your actual code have the double quotes that are missing here?    
 <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_north"    autocomplete='off'>

Comment: You're trying to get `.value` using JS, but the HTML elements do not have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML elements don't have a `value` attribute set, so you can't get North using `.value`

If you're trying to get North from the parent label tag, you can access it this way:

**JS**

```
var form = document.getElementById("info_form");
console.log(form.querySelector("#radio_north").parentNode.innerText);
```

**HTML** (note there was a missing `"` in your question)

```
<form id="info_form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_north" value="north" autocomplete='off'>North
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_south" autocomplete='off'>South
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_east" autocomplete='off'>East
    </label>
</form>
```

**JS Fiddle Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/csqgq1qh/

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

If you need to get the value of the radio, you first have to assign a `value` attribute.  Once you have that, you can get the checked radio's value using some JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<form id="info_form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_north" value="north" checked autocomplete='off'>North
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_south" value="south" autocomplete='off'>South
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio"  id="radio_east" value="east" autocomplete='off'>East
    </label>
</form>
<button id="clicker">Get Value</button>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.getElementById("info_form");
console.log(form.querySelector("input[name='optradio']:checked").value);

/* use an event listener to alert the value when the button is clicked */
document.querySelector("#clicker").addEventListener('click', function() { alert(form.querySelector("input[name='optradio']:checked").value); } )
```

**Updated JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/csqgq1qh/2/

Comment: what if I need to get the value of the clicked/checked radio option?

Comment: I replaced 'radio.north' in `alert(form.elements["optradio"].value);` with the 'optradio' and can get the clicked option. :) Thankx for the help. I also added the value option in my code.

Comment: @QuratulAinShafiq Glad that worked for you!  I updated the answer with an example of how to access the value attribute of the radio elements.